# What tax is owed on money inherited from the US, by a UK citizen?

Tags: united-states, taxes, united-kingdom, inheritance

A deceased aunt of mine who has lived in the US for most of her adult life (50+ years) has recently passed away and left a sum of money in an investment bank (schwab) to be divided up among 4 cousins. I think this was part of a pension?

All the cousins live in the UK and have done their entire lives. The sum of money ends up at about $100k each.

I am very unsure about the tax that should be paid on this money. The investment bank says we either pay 30% to Americas IRS, or pay whatever the tax is to HMRC in the UK. Other info online suggests that tax should have already been paid on the deceased's estate and therefore no tax is due from the money to either the US or the UK. Please help!

Comment: The amount you're talking about us well below the exemption amount for US estate taxes. Since you mentioned a pension, I'm assuming the investment account is a retirement brokerage account (either an IRA or 401(k)). Those types of accounts are contributed to pre-tax and you only pay tax on withdrawal.

Comment: So if I want to withdraw the money to a UK bank account, I have to pay the 30% tax?

Comment: If it's an inherited (traditional) IRA/401k, you might be able to withdraw over several years, possibly keeping your total tax lower.